# Export HTML inside DIV to file using AngularJS + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, export

I'm having a bit of an issue with my current project... and apologies if this is a bit vague as I'm clueless on how to start this part.

I have the following example HTML

```
<div id="exportme">
    I need to be exported
    <br />
    To a HTML document
</div>
<button ng-click="exportDocument()">Export DIV</button>
```

What I would like to happen is, when I click on the `exportDocument()` button the contents inside that DIV are exported to a html file located on the server (`/tmp` or something)

I have no idea how to go about doing something like this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using: 
NodeJS latest
AngularJS 1.6.4

Comment: Sorry! It's part of the page, so users goes to www.bla/#!/PAGE and on there will be that div, once clicked will export said html.

Comment: I think you need to pull it out with `document.getElementById("exportme")`, then convert it to string with `.outerHTML` and send that to NodeJS (_that's beyond me_), possibly with `$http.post(url,data)`

Comment: yes! that makes sense, why did i not think of that! thanks dude! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo without the NodeJS part

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="demo">
    <div id="exportme">
      I need to be exported
      <br /> To a HTML document
    </div>
    <button ng-click="exportDocument()">Export DIV</button>
    <pre>
      {{a}}
    </pre>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('demo', function($scope,$http) {
      $scope.exportDocument = function() {
        $scope.a = document.getElementById("exportme").outerHTML;
        // TODO: send $scope.a to NodeJS
        // $http.post(url,$scope.a);
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```